# Authorizer not executing isAuthozed method

Tags: cakephp, authorization, cakephp-3.2

I'm using [Cakemanager Authorizer](http://cakemanager.org/docs/utils/1.0/components/authorizer/), but remarked that `Authorizer` is not running the `isAuthorized()` method. My config is as follow :

```
$this->loadComponent('Auth', [
        'authenticate' => [
            'Form' => [
                'fields' => ['username' => 'email', 'password' => 'password']
            ],
            'ADmad/HybridAuth.HybridAuth'
        ],
        'loginRedirect' => [
            'plugin' => FALSE,
            'controller' => 'Pages',
            'action' => 'display',
            'home'
        ],
        'logoutRedirect' => [
            'controller' => 'Pages',
            'action' => 'display',
            'home'
        ],
        'authorize' => 'Controller'

    ]);
    $this->loadComponent('Utils.Authorizer');
```

And the `isAuthorized` method in `PagesController` :

```
public function isAuthorized($user)
{

    $this->Authorizer->action(['display', 'contact', 'about', 'tips', 'terms'], function($auth) {
        $auth->allowRole(['*']);
    });

    return $this->Authorizer->authorize();
}
```

But when accessing any of the listed actions, I got redirected to login page. I try this `\Cake\Log\Log::info($this->Authorizer);` and got the following log output :

> Utils\Controller\Component\AuthorizerComponent Object ( [components] => Array ( ) [implementedEvents] => Array ( [Controller.initialize] => beforeFilter ) [_config] => Array ( [roleField] => role_id [Authorizer] => Array ( [roleField] => role_id ) ) )

And I think the Authorizer Component is running `beforeFilter` instead of `isAuthorized`. Am I doing something wrong ?

Comment: Sounds like you are not logged in (ie authenticated)?!

Comment: @ndm, No, the user is not logged in. But unable the access home page (ie display() action).

Comment: Then what you are seeing is the expected behavior. You need to understand the difference between authentication and authorization, that's two different things, the latter depends on the former, ie without successful authentication, there will never be authorizaton. **http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers/components/authentication.html#authorization**

Comment: Oh @ndm, thank you this. I can understand that `isAuthorized()` is called if the user is authenticated. Thank you.